# Google Sheets - Copied sheet and script but encountered error on new sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, coinmarketcap

I recently created a crypto portfolio sheet that pulls data from CMC API to give real time prices. I thought I did such a good job that I would create a sample sheet and share the link with people so they could create their own API KEY and make their own portfolio...

However when I tested it out, by copying the sheet, adding API, my script is giving an error.
Even though it still works perfectly fine on the previous sheet?

**This is the error I am getting:**

Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
coin_price  @ Code.gs:17

It seems to fail to read random functions, as previously I was getting error:

Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'quote')
coin_price  @ Code.gs:31

**Here is my code:**

function coin_price() {
const myGoogleSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Portfolio');
const coinMarketCapAPICall = {
method: 'GET',
uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
qs: {
start: '1',
limit: '5000',
convert: 'USD',
},
headers: { 'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MY-API-KEY' }, // Replace 'insert api' with your API key
json: true,
gzip: true,
}

let myCoinSymbols = [];
const getValues = myGoogleSheetName.getRange('A6:A').getValues(); // Start reading symbols from A6
const numRows = getValues.filter(symbol => symbol[0] !== "").length; // Get the number of non-empty cells in column A
const coinSymbols = getValues.slice(0, numRows);

// Let's iterate
for (let i = 0; i < coinSymbols.length; i++) {
const ticker = coinSymbols[i][0];
const coinMarketCapUrl = `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=${ticker}`;
const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(coinMarketCapUrl, coinMarketCapAPICall);
const txt = result.getContentText();
const d = JSON.parse(txt);
const row = i + 6; // Start inputting prices from row 6

```
// Puts a column of current market prices in dollars into the sheet at B6 and onwards.
myGoogleSheetName.getRange(row, 2).setValue(d.data[ticker].quote.USD.price);
```

}
}

I tried rewriting script, nothing,
I tried changing the name of the sheet hoping it would somehow reboot everything, nothing
I tried adding CMC API using extension API Connector and it worked, but I have custom functions in my script that still aren't working (i.e. its not the API that's the problem)
I tried adjusting the range of where it would read symbols, nothing

Comment: - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried cleaning you code up a bit but I did not wish to paste it into you code because I found it so disorganized that I wasn't sure I was doing it justice.

```
function coin_price() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Portfolio');
  const coinMarketCapAPICall = {
    method: 'GET', uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest', qs: { start: '1', limit: '5000', convert: 'USD', }, headers: { 'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'MY-API-KEY' },
    json: true, gzip: true
  }
  const coinMarketCapUrl = https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=${ticker}; 
  const vs = sh.getRange('A6:A' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();  
  const coinSymbols = vs.slice(0, vs.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < coinSymbols.length; i++) {
    let ticker = coinSymbols[i];
    let result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(coinMarketCapUrl, coinMarketCapAPICall);
    let txt = result.getContentText();
    let d = JSON.parse(txt);
    let row = i + 6; 
    sh.getRange(row, 2).setValue(d.data[ticker].quote.USD.price);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, new to stack and when I pasted the script, the format completely folded on itself, not sure why.

But the issue was actually quite simple, I added an extra row to the sheet after implementing the script, I just had to delete the row add the script, and then re-add the row.

Appreciate the fact that you cleaned it up though. I'm not an expert.

Comment: If there’s anything I can do to help you improve it, let me know